# RHEL 7 allocate physical cores and rams for users

Tags: dell-poweredge, rhel7, multi-core

Dears,

Back at work we have Dell blade server with 64 physical cores, and we intend to use heavy simulations on softwares by multiple users.
My question: Is there a way to assign certain number of cpu cores/rams for each user to use?
Example: user x gets 4 cores and 16GB rams.
So when he runs software like Matlab it will use 4 physical cores and his 16GB of ram preallocated to the user x.

Thanks!

Comment: If Matlab runs under systemd, it is already using cgroups and can limit CPU, memory, etc.  If it runs outside of systemd, then your only limits would be pam limits.conf.  There are ways to put legacy apps under systemd control but that would be a lengthy article vs. a short answer.

Comment: Thanks Aaron so you're suggesting me to use limits.conf file for users, but I dont know if limits can reserve cores and not processes like the nproc tag inside the limits.conf file...

Comment: Exactly, if your app runs outside of systemd, then your options are very limited.  Limits.conf is very old and has very little control over resources.  If you can get MatLab to run under systemd, then you have more options.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I hope its easy and straight forward to configure which I doubt :) also I need other softwares to use with systemd example Ansys. Can you please provide me with an article about this? Many thanks!

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Resource_Management_Guide/index.html